# React Native BackHandler Not Following State Updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

My `backAction` function that's used in `BackHandler` event listener, uses a `stage` state for conditionals, but doesn't follow the state value updates when `stage` is updated by other components, as it gets stuck on the initial state value. and also return true and false don't do anything.

**Expected Behavior:**

If back button is pressed check current stage:

- If stage value is 1 then use `return false` to trigger back button default behavior and navigate back to the previous screen (with out the need to use `navigation.goBack()`).
- If stage value is more that 1 then just decrement the current stage
  value by -1, and `return true` to stop the event bubbling.

**Current Behavior:**

Once back button is pressed:

- Uses and keeps using on each click `stage` initial value of 1 even if it's clear that other components changed it and used it's new value.
- `return false` doesn't even trigger the default behavior of the back button.

**Code To Reproduce:**

```
const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);

const backAction = async () => {
  console.log(stage); // the bug: stage is always 1

  if (stage === 1) {
    console.log("Going back to previous screen!");
    return false;
  } else if (stage > 1) {
    console.log("Setting stage back with -1");
    await setStage((prevState) => prevState - 1);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

  return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
}, []);
```

**Note:** I've used the documentation pattern of assigning `BackHandler.addEventListener` to `backHandler`, and then using it in the events clean up as `backHandler.remove()`. didn't work either, but removed it here for the sake of simplicity.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First: the return value of your event handler is passed to the JS runtime's event listener system. It doesn't accept promises, it doesn't know how to accept promises. But a promise is a truthy value, which means that your handler is effectively returning `true` simply because you marked it `async`.

Second, `setState` is not asynchronous (i.e. is not declared `async`), which means there's no need to `await` it. The code will still run, but there's no benefit. And, since this is the only use of `async` in the handler, removing this allows you to convert your handler to synchronous code, which is a necessity for responding to the `hardwareBackPress` correctly.

<strike>Third, returning `false` is the opposite of what you should do if you want the native behavior to occur. You must return `true` to get default behavior, and `false` otherwise.</strike>

The above paragraph is false. Per [this documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler), you had the right idea about return values. (My apologies; my react-native skills are rusty. I've corrected the code sample below to reflect this.)

Third (for realz): you need to tell React Hooks to re-bind the event handler whenever the value of `stage` changes. The reason this is needed is that the closure will preserve the value of `stage` from when the function is defined, and it doesn't receive updates. You do this by listing that variable among the hook's dependencies. This is why you're seeing stale values at runtime.

Try something like this instead:

```js
const [stage, setStage] = useState(1);

const backAction = () => {
  console.log(stage);

  if (stage === 1) {
    console.log("Going back to previous screen!");
    return false;
  } else if (stage > 1) {
    console.log("Setting stage back with -1");
    setStage((prevState) => prevState - 1);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

useEffect(() => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

  return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
}, [ stage ]);  // <-- this is the part you're missing
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out, thank you for all the gotchas, I'm quite new to react native if it's not clear yet :)
But I'm sorry to say that the solution didn't work :(
I'm still trying tho.

Comment: You don't have to apologies at all, it's alright. But yeah, that's what I tried already, and to be honest so far I tried out of despair every combination I could think of and yet to find what's wrong with this piece of code.

Comment: In that case, I think the bigger problem is the mechanism you're using for having other components update the `stage` variable. How are you exposing control over that value to other components?

Comment: oh simple, I have a screen component, that renders based on location permission response either <success /> or <error /> components. In <success /> I have a state of "stage", the code regarding the issue, a <map/> component,  and <button/> that changes the stage value using "setStage()". the stage value is local to the <success/> component and all it's children (map, button) and it's functions can access it normally.
Now, my only other theory now is that it could be that running BackHandler on the screen component instead of it's child <success/> might change things, gonna try it right now.

Comment: Those details belong in your post. And please elaborate more; don't just paste that comment into your question, it's not precise enough and doesn't contain the information we need.

Comment: Third (for realz): you need to tell React Hooks to re-bind the event handler whenever the value of stage changes.

I actually tried this, had a memory leak, the back handler was working out side of the screen it's ran on, even though I made SURE the event listener is removed. like twice, But will try again, maybe i'm missing something out.

Comment: Worked like a charm, but I'm a bit upset because I'm sure I tried it before, but perhaps within a another solution at the same time, this time no memory leak or nothing weird, thank you so much kind sir, you have a blessed week <3.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes another pair of eyes. Happy coding!

Comment: Wow! Been trying to fix this for a few hours. Simply adding that state to dependency array fixed it! Thanks a lot @Tom